# Is there a way to set the global agenda sorting?

Tags: org-mode

I know that I can setup custom agenda commands with sorting specified using:

```
(org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(priority-down todo-state-up))
```

Is there a way to set the global agenda sorting somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `org-agenda-sorting-strategy` works for built-in agenda
commands. Its default value is

```
((agenda habit-down time-up priority-down category-keep)
 (todo priority-down category-keep)
 (tags priority-down category-keep)
 (search category-keep))
```

So, for the agenda, you should tweak the first line. For example, this
would sort alphabetically by the category name:

```
(setq org-agenda-sorting-strategy
      '((agenda category-up)
        (todo priority-down category-up)
        (tags priority-down category-keep)
        (search category-keep)))
```